# Backup SQL Server 2014 DB in c# not work

Tags: c#, sql-server

I create a program to backup the whole DB from SQL server 2014 , i used the code before it was work perfectly on another laptop `(was working on it coding with c#)`. 
now i'm trying to backup not work at all this is the code:
1/- SqlConnection:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WindowsFormsApplication11.Properties.Settings.Default.database1ConnectionString);
```

2/- textbtn1

```
    private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         textBox1.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
         BackupButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

3/- textbtn2 code :

```
private void BackupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string database = con.Database.ToString();
    try
    {
        if(textBox1.Text==string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter backup file location");
        }
        else
        {
            string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + database + "] TO DISK='" + textBox1.Text + "\\" + "database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd,con))
            {
                if(con.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("database backup done successefully");
                BackupButton.Enabled = false;
            }
       }

    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

** even this code not work and no message show up :p , don't know why ?

i changed every thing , i created a new class called DBconnect :

```
    class DBconnect 
{
    public SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MYSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=MYDBNAME;User ID=sa;Password=12345");


    public void backup(string name_path)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "Backup Database MYDBNAMEto Disk ='" + name_path + ".bak'";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
            myCommand.CommandText = query;
            myCommand.Connection = myConn;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("sauvegarde succès", "sauvegarde", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

in my form i did this :

```
DBconnect conn = new DBconnect();
```

in backup textbtn2 i did this :

```
 string Namefile = textboxBATH.Text + "\\MYDBNAME" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '-') + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().Replace(':', '-');
 Conn.backup(Namefile);
```

in this case i faces this erorr message :

> Cannot open backup device. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.) BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

i thought SQL service might not have permission to the Path where backup bath is supposed to be created . and i create new folder in my Desktop and gave it the permission Read+Write .. and this not work too .. :p

thank you all .

Comment: Backup works. The error is very clear. You tried to save the data to a path to which you don't have access

Comment: On whose desktop did you create that folder? Yours or the server's?

Comment: i created the folder in my desktop  ... i have only one laptop .

Comment: Yes, and the service account has permissions to that folder? Instead of assuming that backup is broken, try the command itself in SSMS.

Comment: my account has full control like the administrator control

Comment: YOur account, not the *service account* under which SQL Server runs. You used a SQL Server login instead of Windows authentication, so the backup will be written using the service account. That's assuming the path isn't something weird. Did you check the contents of `cmd`? Are you able to run it in SSMS ?

Comment: you mean i should create a procedure in SSMS ? 
but i really don't want that cz i will move my program to a client .

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I mean *Are you able to run the command in SSMS*? Run the command. Fix the errors. Copy it back into the code

Comment: show me how to do that in cmd maybe i don't know that . thank you brother .

Comment: Then how do you expect your code to work at all? What does `string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE ...` contain ? Have you tried taking a backup before?

Comment: oh ok i will run the code in SSMS and i will tell you .

Comment: the same error :
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'C:\NEWDB.BAK'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: You realise `C:\NEWDB.BAK'` is the `C:` drive on the server? and that in all recent versions of Windows writes to the root of `C:` require admin privileges.  Write to a destination on the server that the service account running MSSQL has write permissions on.

Comment: Which would never work, because even an administrator will be presented with a UAC dialog if he tries to modify the root drive. Use a different folder. Read the documentation. Find a tutorial. Backup isn't broken

Comment: but why this was work without all this permissions  the same SQL server version and everything .. i am really wondering in this laptop need permissions and other computer work good .
what will  i do in client PC if it happens again ?

Comment: hi brother i have changed the Drive to "D:\" and it worked normal
BACKUP DATABASE MYDB 
TO DISK = 'D:\NEWDB.BAK'
GO